# EER diagram inheritance

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship

In a scenario like below

[image: scenario]

assignee and assigner are keys of developer and tester. how to map the emp_id as a foreign key without getting duplicated?

Comment: Have you come up with any design/model yourself? Can you share it here?

Comment: i thought the only thing can do is, declare primary keys for each tester and developer themselves.

Comment: Can you give an example of the duplication you're trying to avoid?  I see no problem in the design - `assigner` and `assignee` should contain the relevant `emp_id`s.

Comment: yeah I also agree with you. making assignee and assigner  as foreign  keys which referencing the emp_id   will resolve the issue i think.am i right?@reaanb

Answer (score 0):

These are primarily roles for an employee - developer, tester, business analyst etc. One way is to have multiple tables for each role type - so you end up having tables like `Developer`, `Tester` etc. You'll have an `EmployeeID` field as a `foreign key` to the `Employee` table.

The other approach can be (and I'll recommend it) to have one single table called `EmployeeRole` where you have a record for each role an `Employee` can have. This way you'll not have to create a new table every time you come up with a new role. It will just simply be a case of adding a new record in the `EmployeeRole` table. This will also cater for the scenario where an `Employee` performs more than one role - a Developer as well as Tester on different issues.

Comment: but I need to have two foreign keys to the issue table with the employeeId reference one for tester and one for developer how can i achieve that is a still question

Comment: Instead of directly referencing the Employee table, you will have to reference the `EmployeeRole` table (`EmployeeRoleID` column) which will in turn reference the `Employee` table. So to get the `Employee` details on a issue your query would look something like this:

 `SELECT Emp.*
 FROM
   Issue I
   JOIN EmployeeRole ER ON I.TesterID = ER.EmployeeRoleID
   JOIN Employee EMP ON ER.EmployeeID = EMP.EmployeeID`

Comment: Your "solution" doesn't allow referential integrity to be enforced and abuses surrogate keys to create predetermined access paths which will impose extra joins and complexity on queries.

Comment: @reaanb the referential integrity between `Issue` and `Employee` are implemented through `EmployeeRole` table. However, I realize that my answer is overly complicated for this question. It does have a use case which I am happy to discuss outside this question but for this particular scenario all we need is `assigner` and `assignee` to be referencing `emp_id` in the `Employee` table. @Gayan apologies for making this difficult for you!

Comment: its ok amit.I got attention of my mind with a different area with your answer.thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [shared-primary-key](/questions/tagged/shared-primary-key).  Using this technique,  you can use emp-id  as a primary key in the tester and developer tables,  and also as a foreign key that references the employee table.  This is a common practice when implementing an IS-A relationship.